# Iterate Over Dictionary

Tags: python, iteration, python-2.x

The two setups using `print(i, j)` and `print(i)` return the same result. Are there cases when one
should be used over the other or is it correct to use them interchangeably?

```
desc = {'city': 'Monowi', 'state': 'Nebraska', 'county':'Boyd', 'pop': 1}

for i, j in desc.items():
 print(i, j)

for i in desc.items():
 print(i)
```

---

```
for i, j in desc.items():
 print(i, j)[1]

for i in desc.items():
 print(i)[1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: They're functionally equivalent, so use whichever makes your code more readable.

Comment: In Python 3, they are _not_ equivalent: The first prints the items seperated by a space, the second prints a tuple.

Comment: If you need to use the keys and values separately then use the first approach, this is the most common case for iterating over a `dict`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are different if remove parenthesis in print because you are using python 2X

```
desc = {'city': 'Monowi', 'state': 'Nebraska', 'county':'Boyd', 'pop': 1}

for i, j in desc.items():
 print i, j 

for i in desc.items():
 print i
```

output

```
county Boyd
city Monowi
state Nebraska
pop 1
('county', 'Boyd')
('city', 'Monowi')
('state', 'Nebraska')
('pop', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `print(i, j)` and `print(i)` does **not** return the same result.

`print(i, j)` prints the key `i` followed by its value `j`.

`print(i)` prints a tuple containing the dictionary key followed by its value.

Answer (score 0):

`items()` returns a view object which allows you to iterate over the `(key, value)` tuples. So basically you can just manipulate them as what you do with tuples. The [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dictionary-view-objects) may help:

> iter(dictview)
>   Return an iterator over the keys, values or items (represented as tuples > of (key, value)) in the dictionary.

Also I think `print(i, j)[1]` would result in error in Python 3 since `print(i, j)` returns `None`.